# how to subscribe to specific topic inside rout in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have this process for iot device  .

1. Receive message in HTTP request to my server from mobile app-the
   user of app send messge to server via api  to open relay in iot
   device  the app send the device id of the iot device.
2. server Publish message in above step via MQTT to specific topic and Wait for 5
   seconds to receive acth  response from device via MQTT to spesific topic. If response
   is received within 5 seconds the server send success response to app  then user know
   if the action sucsuss or not  , else send
   error response, to original HTTP request in step 1

i didnt found sulustion how to do it and how to subscribe a specific topic thet the device will reply inside the route in nodejs

i  use mqtt of aws-iot core

```
var awsIot = require("aws-iot-device-sdk");
var http = require("http");
const port = "8082";
var url = require("url");
const express = require("express");
const { json } = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
var cors = require("cors");
const { Console } = require("console");
//const { rejects } = require("assert");
//const { resolve } = require("path/posix");
app.use(cors());
var device = awsIot.device({
  keyPath:
    "AWS/d337405f03a230065b9ngngefafa6b908ca03bed63e34f0d01fbf651ca8c58b75-private.pem.key",
  certPath:
    "AWS/d337405f03a230065b97f9efhhhgsfafa6b908ca03bed63e34f0d01fbf651ca8c58b75-certificate.pem.crt",
  caPath: "AWS/roorCA.pem",
  clientId: "testawsconection1", //esp32-erocam-122021
  host: "a2nl9gsbgfihjibb-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
});

async function getReq(topicLisiner) {
  const timeOutPromise = new Promise((reslove, rejects) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      rejects("error time out");
    }, 10000)
  );

  const promisDevice = new Promise((reslove, rejects) => {
    ///
    device.on("connect", function () {
    
      device.subscribe("esp32/pub");

    });
    ///
    device.on(
      "message",
      function (topic, payload) {
        //device.subscribe(topicLisiner);
        console.log("topic1", topic, payload.toString());
        if (topic) {
          if (topic == topicLisiner) {
            device.unsubscribe(topicLisiner);
            device.on("close", function () {
        
              device.unsubscribe(topicLisiner);
    
            });
            reslove(payload.toString());
          }
        } else {
          rejects("error1");
        }
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) rejects(error);
        else {
          reslove(result);
        }
      }
    );
  });
  return Promise.race([promisDevice, timeOutPromise]);
}

app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {


  device.publish("esp32/eran", JSON.stringify({ "open door": "5" }));

  console.log("----------------");

  try {
    const result = await getReq("esp32/pub");
    console.log(result);
    return res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {}

  return res.send("error time out-");


});
```

///

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't.

Mixing a synchronous request/response protocol like HTTP with an asynchronous pub/sub protocol is generally a bad idea unless you are very sure about what you are doing. It would be **MUCH** better to just move the MQTT publish to the mobile app rather than trying to add HTTP in the middle.

Longer answer, it is possible, but it doesn't scale. You can only ever have a single HTTP server to make this work as it need to keep track of all the inflight requests. It also requires the published message to include a unique ID with the request published to the device and the device needs to respond with this id.

You subscribe to a topic that matches all devices and handle them all at once. The following is an example based on the mqtt.js client library but should be a guide to an approach with the AWS library.

```
var waitingRequests = {}

device.on('message', function(topic, message){
  var msg = JSON.parse(message)
  var waiting = waitingRequests[msg.id]
  if (waiting) ({
    waiting.res.send(msg)
    delete waitingRequests[msg.id]
  }
})

//checks every second for timed out requests
setInterval(function(){
  var now = Date.now()
  var keys = Object.keys(waitingRequests)
  for (var key in keys) {
    var waiting = waitingRequests[keys[key]]
    var diff = now - waiting.timestamp;
    if (diff > 5000) {
      //timed out
      waiting.res.send("error timed out")
      delete waitingRequests[keys[key]]
    }
  }
}, 1000)

app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
  device.publish("esp32/eran", JSON.stringify({ "open door": "5", "id": "someId" }));
  waitingRequests["someId"] = { res: res, timestamp: Date.now()}

});
```